# What is a cold/dead field and what is a peeling optimization?

Tags: c++, optimization

In the paper [Loop Recognition in C++/Java/Go/Scala (pdf)](https://days2011.scala-lang.org/sites/days2011/files/ws3-1-Hundt.pdf) we find the following quote in the section *C++ Tunings*:

> *Structure Peeling.* The structure `UnionFindNode` has 3 cold fields:
>   `type_`, `loop_`, and `header_`. Since nodes are allocated in an
>   array, this is a good candidate for peeling optimization. The three
>   fields can be peeled out into a separate array. Note the `header_`
>   field is also dead – but removing it has very little performance
>   impact. The `name_` field in the `BasicBlock` structure is also dead,
>   but it fits well in the padding space so it is not removed.

Can some explain to me what cold/dead fields are, and what a peeling optimization is (I understand what the author did there, but what is the rationale behind it)?

Comment: Strange. Shouldn't it be written in the paper what these terms mean? Or at least where to find their meaning?

Comment: These terms are not mentioned anywhere else in the paper, and google turned up nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Structure peeling` is an optimization where you divide a structure into several ones to improve data locality (in order to reduce cache misses). You separate "hot" data (frequently accessed) from "cold" data (seldomly accessed) into two structures to improve the efficiency of the cache, by maximizing the probability of cache hits.

In the article, the authors decided to move the `type_`, `loop_` and `header_` fields away from the more frequently accessed fields.

For more information, you can have a look at this scientific article about structure layout optimization, which contains a description of structure peeling among other techniques: [Structure Layout Optimizations in the Open64 Compiler: Design, Implementation and Measurements](http://www.capsl.udel.edu/conferences/open64/2008/Papers/111.pdf)

If you have access to the ACM digital library, you can also download [Practical structure layout optimization and Advice](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1122408).

Answer (score 13):

These terms have to do with compilers optimization techniques.

This is what I found [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3742.html) :

> Structure Splitting
>
> Structure splitting is the action of dividing structures into their
>   components. Once accomplished, the components may then be assigned to
>   registers, for faster access. This is a particular advantage when
>   returning a structure from a function, where the whole structure can
>   be returned in registers rather than on the stack.

[Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Structure_Reorganization_Optimization) they say :

> The structure peeling transformation is a particular case of structure
>   splitting in which introduction of pointers is not needed.

Again, [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3742.html) they say :

> Additionally when a variable is dead (when its value will not be used
>   later), the register to which it has been assigned will be reused.